# Writing json to AWS S3 from AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to write a response to AWS S3 as a new file each time.

Below is the code I am using

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=region_name)
s3_obj = s3.Object(s3_bucket, f'/{folder}/{file_name}.json')
resp_ = s3_obj.put(Body=json.dumps(response_json).encode('UTF-8'))
```

I can see that I get a 200 response and the file on the directory as well. But it also produces the below exception :

> [DEBUG]   2020-10-13T08:29:10.828Z.   Event needs-retry.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f2cf2fdfe123>>

My code throws 500 Exception even though it works. I have other business logic as part of the lambda and things work just fine as the write to S3 operation is at the last. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Key (filename) of an Amazon S3 object should not start with a slash (`/`).

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, and forgot to check this space. Cheers!